# Making HTTP callout from salesforce.com functions is possible?

Tags: salesforce-functions

I want to make HTTP callout from salesforce.com functions and download data from Pardot in csv format and store it in salesforce files. is it possible to make such a callout? In documentation as well as in functions recipes could not find any such example.
Also if it is possible to make such callout from functions then endpoint URL to be added in remote site settings under which Org? Can we access compute org? is login to compute space possible?

Comment: Hello [@Ghanekar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/105146/ghanekar), you are asking multiple questions in one. I'll answer the main one. Take into account that this doesn't use the Remote Site Settings from your org, you just make your HTTP Callout from the Function without restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make an HTTP Callout from a Function to a 3rd party site. Just make sure to use any of the available HTTP Request libraries on the language of your choice.

- For Java you can use the [HttpClient](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html)
- For Node.js (JS/TS) you can use either [undici](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)